# spring - <context:property-placeholder> load multiple properties but ignore missing ones

Tags: java, spring, properties-file, property-placeholder

I used the following configuration in my applicationContext.xml

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:system.properties,file:/data/conf/system.properties,file:/data/conf/1033.properties" ignore-unresolvable="true" />
```

to load some placeholders:

1. use these properties defined in `classpath:system.properties`;
2. if file or properties exist in `/data/conf/system.properties`, use them instead of above;
3. if file or properties exist in `/data/conf/1033.properties`, use them instead of above.

Now Spring started ok if both `/data/conf/system.properties` and `/data/conf/1033.properties` exists, but it will throw `rg.springframework.beans.factory.BeanInitializationException: Could not load properties; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: ...` if either of them does not exist.

How to tell spring load these properties but ignore missing ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add `ignore-resource-not-found="true"`

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:system.properties,file:/data/conf/system.properties,file:/data/conf/1033.properties" 
   ignore-unresolvable="true"  
   ignore-resource-not-found="true"/>
```